# Comparing two texts, looking for matching phrases

Tags: text, indexing

I would like to compare two human-language, user-supplied texts. Call them Text A and Text B. Each is the length of a fat novel, i.e., around 150,000 words.

Is there a tool that can help me find all **exact** phrase-matches, anywhere in the text, that are $n$ words long. (For example: Text A starts with "It was the Best of Times, it was the worst of Times; Text B has the phrase "worst of Times" buried somewhere. That comes up as a hit with the specification $n=3$, or $2≤n≤6$.)

Hey, thanks in advance to anyone who can give me pointers! I'm totally new to this, so sorry if this is elementary.

Comment: Hi, you might find some help after I am just leaving you some references you might be interested in. I am not familiar with this area and do not know which methods you could use for the last two points, but at the bottom of the documentation of the [Nearest](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nearest.html) page there are a lot of guides on topics like Text Analysis, Natural Language Processing, Linguistic data, etc. In the [home page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/) of the documentation there are different categories, some that might interest you.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please visit [SequenceAlignment](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceAlignment.html) documentation pages. The question, as posed, is asking many questions and so the likelihood of getting an answer reduces. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, Syed. I have edited the question to narrow it down to the first item. And I'm off to learn about SequenceAlignment. Any other tips are appreciated.

Comment: If I was going to attempt this I'd probably start with `TextStructure`, using the optional second argument `"ConstituentStrings"`, to make a list of the constituent phrases in each text.  Then I'd sort them, compare the two sorted lists. Then I'd do some serious thinking ...

Comment: If you just want to find matches for a string in another string you can use `StringCases` like `StringCases["hat cat dog hat cat", "hat cat"]`

Comment: If you want something more sophisticated maybe the answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/207129/86543) would help